# Detect whether "overflow: auto" works properly (mobile browsers)

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, media-queries, modernizr

I'd like to detect in some "nice" way (Modernizr most likely, but whatever)  whether a layout should have embedded scrollable regions of the page, or else (for some mobile use) should just flow all content as one scrollable mass.

The specific case is a "EULA"-like page, where there's a form with an "I ACCEPT" button or whatever, and then a mass of hideous all-caps legal stuff.  On a big screen I'd like the whole form visible, so I'd like to put the legal stuff in its own scrolling box.  However, on a mobile device that would be kind-of ugly (though I'm no mobile ux expert), so I was thinking of just dropping it all in-line so that the user could read the text (LOL) with simple swipes to scroll, and then at the bottom the buttons would scroll into view.

I suppose I could just check for touch with Modernizr, but that doesn't seem quite right.

*edit* — though I'm pretty sure that what I described would probably be a usability win anyway, the thing is I'm finding that my Android devices won't pay any attention to "overflow: auto" on a `<div>` in the middle of a page.

Comment: It doesn't exist in this suite, but a lot of the techniques in kangax's `cft` project could be helpful: http://kangax.github.com/cft/ - there's even one for a different overflow bug.

Comment: Hmm I'll look at those, but maybe for now (and my immediate purposes have little need for extreme rigor) checking for "touch" might be the thing to do. Touch-driven scroll is the characteristic that's really the issue, overflow bugs or not. Thanks Alex :-)

Answer (score 2):

The approach I've taken is to rely on `Modernizr.touch` and `Modernizr.overflowscrolling` tests.  If Modernizr inserts the `touch` and `no-overflowscrolling` classes in the `html` element in the DOM (or just check `Modernizr.touch` and `Modernizr.overflowscrolling` directly), then I avoid `overflow:auto`. This means that Android devices that mishandle `overflow:auto` do not get it.

This might be an imperfect solution; there might be devices that can handle `overflow:auto` that don't get it in this case.  But that's not exactly the end of the world, at least in my case. And it seems to work correctly for all the most common devices/browsers.

And it has the virtue of being simple. I already had Modernizr loaded for other uses.

Comment: how do u check for Modernizr.overflowscrolling ??

Comment: You need to either build Modernizr with css-overflow-scrolling (you can go to http://modernizr.com/download/ and check the box under Community Add-Ons) or use addTest() as shown at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css-overflow-scrolling.js.

Comment: ok did that...  but the issue is that it says that the property is supported even though its not working :(  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483397/test-for-overflow-yauto-returning-true-on-android-3-even-though-it-doesnt-wor#comment13549712_10483397

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the `Modernizr.overflowscrolling` checks for the `overflow-scrolling` css property, not for whether the device can scroll content within a `div` using `overflow: auto`.

In fact, in my recent testing, the Nexus 5 actually returns `Modernizr.overflowscrolling` as `false`, so it cannot be relied on.

This very small script (with no dependencies) seems to enable touch scrolling for devices (Android 2.3) lacking support... 
http://chris-barr.com/2010/05/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/

**Link to repo:**
https://github.com/chrismbarr/TouchScroll

Comment: You'de better include the script here as if link changes your answer would get invalid.