# test for overflow-y:auto returning true on android < 3 even though it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-browser, browser-support

im developing a webapp for android. At a place i need to find whether **overflow-y:auto** is supported or not in the browser because i need to scroll a div. 
 
But tests for this return true in **android < 3**, telling that its supported, but when used it doesnt work the way its expected, i.e., the div with

```
overflow-y:auto
```

doesnt scroll.

Is there any credible way to see if this property is supported in a browser. i wrote this test using modernizr, but it always returns true, meaning that its supported.

```
Modernizr.addTest('overflowauto', function(){
var bool = false;
var testProp = "overflow-y";
var testVal = "auto";
var styles = Modernizr._prefixes.join(testProp + ":" + testVal + "; ");
var ret = true;
ret =  Modernizr.testStyles('#modernizr { '+styles+' }', function(elem, rule){
    for(var i = 0; i < Modernizr._prefixes.length; i++) {
        bool = (window.getComputedStyle ?
                getComputedStyle(elem, null) :
                elem.currentStyle)[Modernizr._prefixes[i] + testProp] == testVal;

        if(bool) break;
    }

    return bool;

});
return ret;
```

});

But clearly its not working when i use it.
Please tell me **a credible way to find if the property is safe to use**, or what can i do about it.

Comment: I just dealt with this myself. I believe that technically the overflow values are supported, but that the rendering engine chooses to handle them exactly like overflow:hidden. I looked into doing scrolling via javascript, but that quickly became a huge mess.

Comment: i guess the only way now is to detect the user agent and choose between overflow:auto and something like iscroll.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Modernizr.addTest("overflowscrolling",function(){
    return Modernizr.testAllProps("overflowScrolling");
});
```

Then check for the `overflowscrolling` or `no-overflowscrolling` class that Modernizr will insert into the `html` element in the DOM.  This seems to work correctly for iOS and Android devices. (Or just check the value of `Modernizr.overflowscrolling` directly.)

Because `overflowscrolling` is specific to certain browsers/devices (e.g., recent iPhones), I check for `Modernizr.touch` as well.  If it's not a touch device, I assume it can handle overflow scrolling.  Since Androids are touch devices, they will be tested with `Modernizr.overflowscrolling` but you don't have to test, say, Chrome on a laptop (which will return false but can handle `overflow:auto` just fine).

So the test may be imperfect, but it seems to do the right thing for all the use cases I care about that I've tested:  All modern desktop browsers, recent iPhones, and Android 2.X devices.  If you have a wider array of devices/browsers to support, you'll have to test those and tweak as appropriate.

Comment: Chrome false positive is specifically addressed in the second paragraph.